# Gitlab DNS Entry For Kubernetes Setup?

Tags: dns, kubernetes, gitlab, minikube, gitlab-omnibus

I have a n00b question about setting up gitlab on a kubernetes.  I'm running a basic [minkube](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube) cluster on my home machine and I want to install gitlab onto it.  The setup instructions [note the following prequesite](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/install/kubernetes/gitlab_chart.html#prerequisites):

> The ability to point a DNS entry or URL at your GitLab install

How do I do this?  **What is the basic mechanism for setting up a "DNS entry" on a home machine running minikube?**  There example shows:

> externalUrl: 'http://gitlab.example.com'

**If I own a domain how would I set this up?  Why does the setup need an external URL?**

Thank you in advance for you consideration and response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll be setting it up with a nodeport and can access it normally through that. If you really want a DNS entry you can just add one in your hosts file at `/etc/hosts`:

```
[minikube ip] myfakelocalgitlabendpoint.com
```

You can get minikube's IP by running `minikube ip`.

Comment: So are you saying a simple `kubectl expose deployment --type=NodePort` is what the requirements are describing?

Comment: Yes that should be enough.